# matplotlib won't plot line of same x values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having some trouble getting matplotlib to plot a graph if my Y values are all the same.

I am plotting a graph of temperature against time, and I have found that if my temperatures are all the same I get no line plotted, as soon as a temperature change is added to the plot, the line is then drawn.

I have been able to force it to draw the line always by initialising my list of temperatures with a value of zero (0), but that only works assuming the temperature isn't at zero for any time.

Is there a way I can cause it to plot my graph properly without priming with fake values?

Fields:

```
    temperature = []
    time = []
    minY = 0
    maxY = 0
```

Setting (on sensor poll):

```
    temp = float(params['temp'][0])
    time = datetime.now()
    self.temperature.append(temp)
    self.time.append(time)
```

Plot:

```
    plt.figure()
    plt.xlabel("Time")
    plt.ylabel("Temperature (Celcius)")
    plt.title("Temperature in ...")
    plt.ylim(self.minY,self.maxY)
    plt.plot(self.time,self.temperature, "c")
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
    plt.savefig("temp.svg")
```

**Edit: If I set plot type to "o" (circles) when I call plot, I can see the circles on the same line, if I switch back to the default line type, I see nothing.**

**Edit2: Switching output format to png produces the line correctly. Why is SVG not doing so?**

Comment: Can you share the code you use to produce the plot?

Comment: Matplotlib will happily plot a line of constant values. There's absolutely no need to initialize your list with zeros.  What's probably happening is that the line is plotted near the bottom of the plot, and you have a left-over 0 in your array that changes the auto-scaling of the limits.  Try doing something like `plt.margins(0.5)` and see if that helps.

Comment: Actually, it's not plotted anywhere near the bottom, it's centered and I do some manual axis set-up for that. I'll attached snippets.

Comment: Try to add to your Y values this Y+x-x before ploting, x should be an array. In your example try to plot self.temperature+self.time-self.time

Comment: @freude I'm sorry, I don't understand. You want to add the X array to Y then subtract it again, before I plot? Can you explain why, or how this might help?

Comment: There is nothing to explain before you try. If it works, I will give some explanations. Consider this as a diagnostic code and just let me know if it works

Comment: @freude Your explanation isn't explicit enough, I assumed you want me to add/subtract the lists with each other, which I can't do as I receive an error for unsupported operand "-" on lists.

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted. Then convert list to array using numpy.array(self.temperature) or numpy.asarray(self.temperature)

Comment: @freude Now I have unsupported operand + on float and datetime.datetime

Comment: I meant to do it only for the plot function: plt.plot(numpy.array(self.time),numpy.array(self.temperature), "c")

Comment: Tried that, still no line. I don't think it's a type issue, It's something to do with the fact the values are all the same, it's refusing to plot the line, if I have temperatures of 25.0 and 25.0, I get no line, but if I have 25.0 and 25.5 I do get a line. EDIT: If I change type to "o" (circles), I see the circles.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31451/discussion-between-hamid-and-freude)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out (after I inspected the content of the SVG file) there is nothing wrong with the code or with matplotlib, it turns out that **Google Chrome** refuses to display the straight line in the SVG.

I tried the output in Illustrator and Internet Explorer and it works fine.

Comment: Can you create an issue on the github site for this just to check that the svg output is correct (and the issue really is chrome rendering it wrong, not the svg being wrong and illustrator IE handling the brokenness better).